# Using Flutter, how can I trigger onSubmitted() of TextField on iOS?

Tags: dart, flutter

Please take a look at the following Flutter code snippet: it creates a `TextField` that is intended as a single line input field tat will submit its value when Return is pressed:

```
child: new TextField(
  decoration: _deco,
  maxLines: 1,
  autofocus: true,
  onSubmitted: (newValue) {print(newValue);},
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      strTemperature = newValue.trim();
    });
  })),
```

On the iOS Simulator the corresponding app looks as follows:

[image: Screenshot of my sample app]

As you can see the widget is configured with `maxLines = 1`, but when I click the Return key on the onscreen keyboard, line feeds are insert. Please spot the narrow blue cursor a couple of lines below the widget. Also, I see no console output, which should be the case because of my `onSubmitted()` lambda.

Am I configuring the text field correctly, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like it's actually just a bug in the iOS version of Flutter. Filed [issue #9839](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9839).